# Visifire Inquiry

Tags: silverlight, xaml, visifire

Is there a way to change the scroll viewer style of the vertical scroll viewer of the legend of a pie chart in Visifire XAML?

Here is my code:

```
<visifire:Chart x:Name="EmployeeMasterFileChart" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="4,0,4,4" MaxWidth="500">
                        <visifire:Chart.PlotArea>
                            <visifire:PlotArea Background="Transparent" />
                        </visifire:Chart.PlotArea>
                        <visifire:Chart.Legends>
                            <visifire:Legend x:Name="Legend0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" EntryMargin="5"
                            Padding="10" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Normal" ShadowEnabled="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" LightingEnabled="False"/>
                        </visifire:Chart.Legends>

                        <visifire:Chart.Titles>
                            <visifire:Title FontSize="12" Text="Title" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                        </visifire:Chart.Titles>

                        <visifire:Chart.Series>

                            <visifire:DataSeries RenderAs="Pie" LabelEnabled="false" Bevel="True" ShadowEnabled="true" Cursor="Hand" 
                                LightingEnabled="False" BorderColor="DarkBlue" 
                                BorderThickness=".24" ShowInLegend="True" IncludePercentageInLegend="True">

                                <visifire:DataSeries.DataPoints> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jan" YValue="5509"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Feb" YValue="2047"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Mar" YValue="10047"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Apr" YValue="8508"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="May" YValue="6022"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jun" YValue="9047"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jul" YValue="7508"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Aug" YValue="5222"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Sep" YValue="3698"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Oct" YValue="5754"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Nov" YValue="8756"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Dec" YValue="2340"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jan" YValue="5509"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Feb" YValue="2047"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Mar" YValue="10047"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Apr" YValue="8508"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="May" YValue="6022"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jun" YValue="9047"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jul" YValue="7508"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Aug" YValue="5222"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Sep" YValue="3698"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Oct" YValue="5754"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Nov" YValue="8756"/> 
                                    <visifire:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Dec" YValue="2340"/> 
                                </visifire:DataSeries.DataPoints> 

                            </visifire:DataSeries>
                        </visifire:Chart.Series>
                    </visifire:Chart>
```

Comment: Whether you are working with Silverlight or WPF?

Comment: I guess you want ScrollBar style of the vertical scroll viewer of the legend..am I right? Your text is confusing *Is there a way to change the scroll viewer style of the vertical scroll viewer of the legend..*

Answer (score 3):

**I guess you want to change ScrollBar style of the vertical scroll viewer of the legend**

Currently there is no direct option to set the Style of the vertical ScrollBar present in Vertical ScrollViewer in Legend. But you can try the workaround below.

You just need to create a Global style for ScrollBar under the scope of Chart. Set Template property for the ScrollBar and modify it according to your need. Checkout the example below.

[image]

**XAML**

```
 <vc:Chart Height="300" Width="500">
            <vc:Chart.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                             ..................
                             ......Here you need to edit Template of the ScrollBar....
                             ..................
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

            </vc:Chart.Resources>
            <vc:Chart.Titles>
                <vc:Title FontSize="12" Text="Title" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
            </vc:Chart.Titles>
            <vc:Chart.Legends>
                <vc:Legend HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center"></vc:Legend>
            </vc:Chart.Legends>

            <vc:Chart.Series>

                <vc:DataSeries RenderAs="Pie" LabelEnabled="false" Bevel="True" ShadowEnabled="true" Cursor="Hand" 
                    LightingEnabled="False" BorderColor="DarkBlue" 
                    BorderThickness=".24" ShowInLegend="True" IncludePercentageInLegend="True">

                    <vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jan" YValue="5509"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Feb" YValue="2047"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Mar" YValue="10047"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Apr" YValue="8508"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="May" YValue="6022"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jun" YValue="9047"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jul" YValue="7508"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Aug" YValue="5222"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Sep" YValue="3698"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Oct" YValue="5754"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Nov" YValue="8756"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Dec" YValue="2340"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jan" YValue="5509"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Feb" YValue="2047"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Mar" YValue="10047"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Apr" YValue="8508"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="May" YValue="6022"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jun" YValue="9047"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Jul" YValue="7508"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Aug" YValue="5222"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Sep" YValue="3698"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Oct" YValue="5754"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Nov" YValue="8756"/>
                        <vc:DataPoint AxisXLabel="Dec" YValue="2340"/>
                    </vc:DataSeries.DataPoints>

                </vc:DataSeries>
            </vc:Chart.Series>
        </vc:Chart>
```

You can download **setting-scrollbar-style-in-legend-workarround.zip** file from the link below.

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=61995e3895be1728&sc=documents&id=61995E3895BE1728%21125#